# Passing jsp tag attribute to Struts 2 tags

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

I am creating a new tag in jsp, named `RequiredLabel` , but I can not pass tag attribute to struts label ( The css are based on YAML)

The tag will be used as:

```
<myTag:RequiredLabel name="amount"/>
```

The label should be get from struts as it must be localized.

```
<%@tag description="Renders a label with required css and error label" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@attribute name="name" required="true" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

 <!--Here ${name} works fine --> 
<p class="ym-message" id="${name}Error" />
<!-- Here I can not pass the name to s:label tag -->
<s:label key="form.label.%{name}" cssClass="ym-required" />
```

I tried `#attr.name` and `#param.name` but none of them worked!

Do you know any solution ?!

Answer (score 0):

I just find a way to do that, but I think it is not the best:

```
<c:set var="labelName" value="form.label.${name}" />
<label class="ym-required"> 
             <s:text name="%{#attr.labelName}" />
</label>
```

The `s:label` does not accept `%{#attr.labelName}` parameter